# Adding title to file field in a content type

Tags: entities, nodes, files

I am making a change to an already existing site.

There is a content type called lesson, and one of its fields is called 'File'. It is being displayed using the "Generic File" format in the content type's display settings which results in a link with a file icon and the filename.

My task is to make the field label as 'Title' of the field instead of the "filename". So: I need to somehow add a file title field.. I could make this just another field in the display, but how would I include it in my display? Is there a preferred way of doing this?

Comment: overriding the node template for your content type can be a possible way.Other wise try out file formatters module. (https://drupal.org/project/file_formatters)
- it looks like you can do this at your custom module level as well using hook_field_display_alter(&$display, $context)(https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_display_alter/7)

Comment: What I'm worried about is how to associate the new 'title' with the already exisiting file file fields while maintaining the existing information